# Open en existing infoWindow upon load of the webpage

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've included a google map on my webpage with a marker at the location. What I want to add is an existing infoWindow of that location when the page loads.
This is the code i have:

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.257195, 3.716563),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.257195, 3.716563),
        map: map
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

screenshot: http://puu.sh/gMtoB/16312f42b7.jpg

Now the "AXA..." is an existing point of interest on google maps, how would i go about that my marker is actually 'linked' to that existing point of interest with the infowindow opened by default.

in short: i would like a marker on that location with the infowindow opened when the webpage loads.

Comment: You can't access the POI marker information programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution would be to first find the `place_id` and then add your marker using the place ID you found rather than using longitude and latitude.

I created a live demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/qzo41qzd/

There is also an example in the documentation about placing a marker on the google map using `place_id`:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#placeid